# Which widget is best to display lots of images?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I want to display lots of images . Which wx widget is best for this purpose?
Please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUXlD.jpg) to see the desired GUI. Also if panel is to be used then how to attach a scrollbar to the panel.
Any sample code/reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: easiest method is probably a ListCtrl with style LC_ICON

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [`ThumbnailCtrl`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl.html).

Just play with the example provided in the link. Put the script in a **folder containing images** and then run it to see it in action.